# Install Android Emulator without Android Studio in Ubuntu - Could not determine SDK root

Tags: android, bash, android-studio, android-emulator, ubuntu-20.04

While installing the android emulator on Ubuntu 20.04,
after running the command for accepting the updated .bashrc file path, the following errors occurred.

- Error: Could not determine SDK root.
- Error: Either specify it
  explicitly with --sdk_root= or move this package into its expected
  location: /cmdline-tools/latest/*

[Terminal Commands and Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeHlk.png)

The .bashrc file has been updated as follows

[.bashrc exported pathway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8RrR.png)

The manual installation has been ignored and I need to install the emulator without the Android Studio.

- I have been following [these steps](https://medium.com/@_illusionist_/installing-android-sdk-without-android-studio-in-ubuntu-for-reactnative-f4a4d1a2ee96) for the installation process.

Comment: You should reload the `.bashrc` after making changes to it. Either use `source ~/.bashrc` or logout and login again.

Comment: I tried that too. But still have the issue installing the SDK in Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the emulator details are in the `.android` folder in gome. SDK routes and the `avd` routes are in there